# Create a string with escape characters '\x' and user input in python

Tags: python, string, hex

I am trying to create a string with user input with '\x' escape character

I am doing something like this -

```
    def create_hex_string(a, b): # a and b are integers of range (0-255)
        # convert decimal to hex and pad it with 0
        # for eg: 10 -> 0x0a
        ahex = "{0:#0{1}x}".format(register,4)
        bhex = "{0:#0{1}x}".format(value,4)
        str = "\x08\x{}\x00\x{}".format(ahex[2:], bhex[2:])
        return str
```

When I try to execute this, the escape characters are no more relevant and it gives me an error.

I also tried to use literal strings to create my hex string with user inputs, something like -

```
str = r'\x08\x{}\x00\x{}'.format(ahex[2:], bhex[2:])
```

But I don't find a way to convert a literal string back to a non literal one which can identify the escape characters.

I also tried to see how re.escape() works, but it escapes all characters except ASCII. Any pointers regarding this would be really appreciated.

---

**Better explanation**

I have a peripheral hardware device with registers. I can set a specific value in a specific register in the device over a socket.

```
sock.send("\x80\x01")
```

This command only works if it is a double quoted string, so the \x escape character has a meaning.
The command above would set register 128 to value 1 because-
0x80 = 128
0x01 = 1

On that line of thought, I created a function

```
1   def create_hex_string(register, value): # a and b are integers of range (0-255)
2       # funky stuff to convert register and value to hex.
3       # reghex = hex value of register (128 = 80 in hex)
4       # valhex = hex value of value (1 = 01 in hex)
5       str = "\x{}\x{}".format(reghex, valhex)
6   return str

7   cmd = create_hex_string(128, 1)
8   sock.send(cmd)
```

If you see, line 5 would give an error, it does not accept.
Instead of double quoted string in line 7, I used a literal string with format.

```
5    str = r'\x{}\x{}'.format(reghex, valhex)
```

With this I lost the significance of the escape characters.

I hope this helps to understand the problem better. Let me if I missed something, and I will add that in the next edit.

Comment: Please give an example of the input and expected output of your function. It appears that you want the resulting string to be four bytes long. The first byte with a value of 8, the 3rd a NUL byte, and the second and fourth bytes to have the values equal to the numbers that are passed in. Is that correct?

Comment: Let me give an example - 
if I send the parameters as -> a=128, b=1
then my hex values after the format function execution would be -
ahex = 0x80
bhex = 0x01

str = "\x08\x80\x00\x01"

Does this make sense?

Comment: See my answer. If that doesn't help, please create a [mcve]. Please create the shortest possible **complete** program that demonstrates the error. Please include the actual and expected output of your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a one-character string from a integer value using the `chr()` function.

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
def create_hex_string(a, b): # a and b are integers of range (0-255)
    return "\x08{}\x00{}".format(chr(a), chr(b))

s = create_hex_string(65, 66)
assert s[0] == '\x08'
assert s[1] == 'A'
assert s[2] == '\x00'
assert s[3] == 'B'
assert s == "\x08\x41\x00\x42"

# The example from OP's comment:
assert create_hex_string(128, 1) == "\x08\x80\x00\x01"
```

Comment: This works like a charm. I should have thought of using the chr() function myself. Thanks Rob